# Visual bug using accent marked characters

Tags: bug, design, font

Reading this answer I found that á and è (and also right now in this question) characters from `Déjà Dup` are shown different than the other characters (they are less "bold" than the others):

Link: [Why does Déjà Dup say there is no space left?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67397/why-does-deja-dup-say-there-is-no-space-left)

[image]

[image]

Is this my problem with Firefox 21 in Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS or is a problem of the web (I don't know if the previous design had this problem)?

EDIT: I can see that several people have the same problem. Then, the problem is from client side or server side?

Comment: The same with: ă, Ă, â, Ă, î, Î, ș, Ș, ț, Ț so on. See my name...

Comment: German diacritics are affected as well: ü ä ö ß.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu You come MORE bold, actually, on your userpage

Comment: This affects me on Chromium as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember this problem, and I don't know what caused it. Fortunately, **this bug seems to have gone away**, perhaps due to a site redesign.

It looks like this now in Chromium in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS [60.0.3112.78-0ubuntu0.16.04.1293]:

[image: screenshot showing the same page as mentioned in the question, from Chromium in Ubuntu]

In Firefox in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS [54.0+build3-0ubuntu0.16.04.1]:

[image: screenshot showing the same page as mention in the question, from Firefox in Ubuntu]

In Chrome in Windows 8.1 [Version 60.0.3112.90 (Official Build) (64-bit)]:

[image: screenshot showing the same page as mention in the question, from Chrome in Windows]

In Firefox in Windows 8.1 [54.0.1 (32-bit)]:

[image: screenshot showing the same page as mention in the question, from Firefox in Windows]